# Is Star Trek set in our future, or is it an alternate universe?

Tags: star-trek, timeline

If I recall correctly, the Eugenics Wars were supposed to have occurred in the 1990s and World War 3 is supposed to happen relatively early in the 21st century. Obviously, the Eugenics Wars did not happen and it doesn't look like we're really on track for WW3 too soon either - at least, not the type of WW3 that Star Trek expects.

Does this mean the Star Trek universe is really no longer supposed to be set in *our* future? If so, when did the timelines diverge? Were they *ever* really the same, or should we presume the Star Trek universe to be *totally* alternate to ours?

Comment: Related, though I don't quite think it's duplicate: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28404/has-star-trek-ever-addressed-why-our-timeline-is-different-than-theirs?rq=1

Comment: All fiction that has specific dates runs into this problem, time doesn't stop moving forward and the universe is unwilling to adhere to the script. I don't know that it's useful or proper to imagine therefor that science fiction (or even non-SF fiction) is set in an alternate universe of the sort science fiction implies.

Comment: Question assumes that all of us here, now, are living in the same timeline. Lacking evidence pointing in that direction, it seems just as likely we each live in our own timeline which interacts with that of all others to form the consensual now. That'd produce the requiredf infinitude of alternate universes, and leave us all without even a ghost of a chance of labeling any timeline the one 'true' timeline.

Comment: I think this question has as much merit as many of the questions asked here. Certainly as much as "How many aliens has Captain Kirk slept with?" Yes, it is difficult to answer effectively but does not mean it SHOULDN'T be. Just my opinion.

Comment: Well, if you believe Sarah Connor... http://www.screenused.com/images/t2/nofate/NoFateCap4.jpg

Comment: Not constructive?!? This is an excellent question and could have an answer by viewing producers notes, canon reference books, etc. 7 upvotes, over a thousand views, an answer with five upvotes, no down votes, an accepted answer, a comprehensive answer, but it's not constructive... As a matter of fact my answer would be the opposite of the answer given below, it is in fact our universe with many proofs given. However it's closed so no chance at giving an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Alternate Timeline/Universe

**Clearly, the Star Trek Prime Universe is an alternate universe from our own. The point of divergence is unclear, but is likely to have occurred between the 1960s and their own 1990s by which time [The Eugenic Wars](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Eugenics_Wars) was thought to be underway. The further divergence of the Star Trek 2009 universe makes it an alternate of the Prime Universe which supposedly diverged from OUR universe.**

- With the Dark Age brought on by the Eugenic Wars and the later [World War III](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/World_War_III) (2026-2053) it is possible information about the era was incorrect and the Eugenic Wars may have started much later. With our current level of genetic advancement, it is possible the Eugenic Wars may have started between now and what was thought to be the World War III period in Federation history.
- Considering how often the Enterprise and her crew had traveled to the past, it could be thought several other incidents could be equally to blame. In all cases, though, all the events were believed to have been resolved with statistical satisfaction because the Federation timeline continued to exist.
- If there was a divergence from the our timeline, such a divergence would have had to occurred after [**Star Trek IV: The Voyage Home**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_IV:_The_Voyage_Home), in which the Enterprise crew arrives in what would have been 1986. Since the crew of the Enterprise played fast and loose with the local timeline during that event, it is possible they caused the divergence by their presence.
- Dr. Gillian Taylor of the Cetacean Institute in Sausalito (and a native of 1986) travels to the Federation future with the Enterprise crew as a caretaker to the humpback whales. The introduction of transparent aluminum by Commander Montgomery Scott to the timeline could have also had an effect as well.

**NOTE: Their return to the Federation future did not indicate they did not alter the past. The alteration of the past may have simply lead to the Federation forming anyway. Indeed, their alterations may have indeed help to cause the Federation to exist. This is further corroborated in the novelization of the film, Commander Scott is aware that Dr. Marcus "Mark" Nichols (Alex Henteloff), the Plexicorp scientist with whom he and McCoy deal, was its "inventor," and concludes that his giving of the formula is a predestination paradox/bootstrap paradox.**

#### Outside the Federation Universe

Truth be told, I would always classify a universe of science fiction, no matter where it supposedly starts as an alternate universe based on the simple idea:

- Any plausible universe that starts as an idea in OUR universe is automatically set apart from our universe. (See: [many-worlds interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation))The very existence of the idea, causes a transformation of our universe (or in the case of the [alternate or parallel universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_universe_%28fiction%29)) so that it is different and will have different parameters and results.
- Consider the transformation of our universe from the creation of the Star Trek Universe. Once our universe was exposed to ideas from the Trek-verse, our technology evolved. Scientists began creating the technology from Star Trek because they believed it could be done, thought it should be done, or thought they could create it because they were presented with the idea through the show.

[image]

- The advancements of the Federation Universe were supposedly 300 years in the future but scientists in our time, inspired by the show have already begun creating that technology TODAY. Thus our world (influenced from the Trek-verse) developed cellular phones, digital tablets, molecular teleportation, virtual computers on silicon wafers, and even new theories such as the [Alcubierre Drive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive)

[image]

So the existence of the Star Trek series in our universe may have derailed the very events the show was attempting to chronicle as our future history. Life imitates art and timelines may indeed be changed by that imitation and technological innovation. What this may mean is a future more fantastic than the one theorized by Star Trek writers will come about in OUR timeline as a result of our desire to create THAT alternate future.

Comment: If I remember right, there was also that timeline-incident in VOY, where the Voyager was brought somewhere around 1990/2000 by a temporal agent (or something). There they figure out that the computer-revolution (speak, fast and big jump forward in computer technology) only happened because some guy found the timeship of the 29th century. Though, I failed to see the second episode and so don't know if they corrected that.

Comment: @Bobby [Future's End](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future%27s_End_(episode)), and [second part](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Future%27s_End,_Part_II_(episode)).  They didn't correct it, because the jump in technology was part of their history and correcting it would erase the Federation.  (Not that they could anyway; the timeship landed in the 60s and Voyager was simply dragged through time accidentally and happened to land in the 90s)

Comment: I think the biggest argument for why any fictional universe has to be different to our own is because otherwise captain picard could in theory uncover old start trek episodes with precise details of what happened in it.